# Visualizing processed data using pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am building a simple pipeline with `LinearRegression` as model and `PowerTransform` as preprocessor using sklearn api.

```
pipe = make_pipeline(PowerTransformer(), LinearRegression())
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Is there anyway I can view my processed data, that is, what are its values after `PowerTranformer()` was applied?

Comment: Yes!  Have a look at `pipe.named_steps`.

Answer (score 0):

You could directly index the `pipeline` object to know the results at different stages.

## Example:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

X, y = make_regression(random_state=42)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)
pipe = make_pipeline(PowerTransformer(), LinearRegression())
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)

pipe[:-1].transform(X_train)
# gives the output of step before the last one

out:

array([[ 1.3943071 , -0.00667248,  0.97089379, ..., -0.63150152,
        -1.04187899,  1.71484236],
       [-1.03916027, -0.32532997,  0.4217364 , ..., -1.04162402,
        -0.85071242, -0.70675717],
       [-1.60758253,  1.04564138, -0.6969723 , ..., -0.52590329,
         0.28850367, -2.08419445],
       ...,
       [ 0.59368446, -2.03290969, -0.64727248, ..., -0.42158375,
        -0.59520549,  0.24687111],
       [ 0.26295331,  0.10787868,  0.24495677, ..., -0.42095777,
        -0.4334757 ,  0.93170649],
       [-0.4053615 , -0.68909058,  1.57818766, ...,  0.11343053,
         0.68360015,  0.0523744 ]])
```